# Animation doesn't export to glb file

Tags: export

I've got two  object that are connected with a cable. The cable is hooked to the two objects. In Blender the cable moves to the new location when I move one of the objects to the new location. I made an animation of the object move but when I export the animation to **.glb (glTF file format)** the object animates, but the cable is not animating. I  have made an NLA track but it still does not work. Who can help me exporting this 3d-model to **.glb** with all objects animated properly.

[image: tester]

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can try it out ourselves and see what you did. thx.

Comment: Hello Chris, I'am new on this forum. I want to share the file can I copy the python code directly here? or is there another way? thx

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your reaction, I am new on this forum, but how do I share my blend file with you?

Comment: You can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it. The file needs to be smaller than 30Meg or you'll have to find another file sharing site.

Comment: Hi Chris, here is the link to the blend file. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=0WPVOrrM" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/0WPVOrrM/)

Comment: Others will probably have the answer to this as I don't know that much about exporting animations, but no export format understands Blender's modifiers (Hook and Subdivision in your case) and I guess you'd have to convert the cable Curve to a mesh before exporting too.

Comment: Thx for your comment Chris.

Comment: i think this video here could help you: https://forum.sketchfab.com/t/exporting-an-animation-from-a-bezier-curve/32164/3 basically he converts the curve movement to a rig movement, which can be exported. Curve/hook animations cannot be exported AFAIK.